# All Laravel doc blocks are three lines and each line is shorter than the previous

Tags: laravel

I've noticed that all the Laravel comments follow the same style: paragraphs of three lines when the following line is shorter (by three characters) than the previous.

i.e:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
```

I've found a few articles about it on Reddit, and on another Laravel website.
But nothing on how they do it.
Any idea what tool do they use to make this happen? Or is it manually?

Comment: There are plugins available for editors to help manage multi-line comments like this. https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs for example. I don't know that Laravel's style has an official name.